# Managing print jobs - Output jobs from different users to different trays

Tags: printing, network-printer, print-server

Is there a way from any printer vendor, or perhaps with Windows Print Spooling to send print jobs from different users to output on a different tray?  For example, slipping smaller jobs in between larger jobs and popping them out on tray 2 while the big job comes out on tray 1?  Further example - Bob, Sally and Victoria all print to the same printer at the same time, which has 3 trays.  Can each of their jobs automatically (without their intervention) be output to trays 1, 2, and 3 respectively?

To be clear, I'm not asking about paper trays, or separator pages.  I want either manage this with MFP firmware, or somehow with the print spooler service.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a function of the printer/print driver?  Pretty sure I've seen some of the more massive, more insanely expensive MFPs exhibit this behavior, but to be honest, all I could think was "what a waste of money," so I never paid much attention.  as the saying goes... hell is other people using printers.

Comment: I can imagine a crazy scenario w/ Ghostscript, a fake Postscript print queue, the "RedMon" port monitor, and multiple queues, each configured for a different default tray for the same physical printer. I'll leave it to you to figure out the crazy scheme I'm thinking of. It could work. I've got a Customer w/ an amusing scenario that we cobbled a solution together that would do some of this. It took a large output job for a label printer and used a fake print queue and a program to break the job into 1-job-per-label so that the whole job wouldn't restart when the printer ran out of labels.

Comment: If you create a smart profile in Print&Share, you should be able to add recognition on the user that prints the job and then create channels that print to specific tray as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just configure the printer settings on each desktop to default to a different tray.

Comment: That's not going to enable the "small job slipped inside a bigger job functionality, though.